# How can I exclude a specific character combination from my regular expression?

Tags: regex

For example, suppose I want to search for strings beginning with two capital letters:

[A-Z][A-Z]

but I want to exclude strings beginning with 'AB'. How do I incorporate the exclusion into my regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

`(?!AB)[A-Z]{2}`

explanation:
`(?!AB)`: negative lookahead: excludes strings beginning with `AB`
`[A-Z]{2}`: matches 2 capital letters

Answer (score 1):

The direct solution:

```
([B-Z][A-Z]|A[AC-Z])
```

In other words, if it starts with a capital Ietter other than A, then any second capital will do, but if it starts with an A, the second letter cannot be B so it must be A or in the range C-Z.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Z](?!B)[A-Z]
```

The `(?!B)` bit says "match any letter, but not if it's followed by B".

Comment: That won't match `BB`.